# Haskell - map list of integers to their square roots

Tags: haskell

I created a little function that map list of integers to their square roots. the code itself is simple:

```hs
f x = map sqrt [1..x]
```

With the default type inference, it can be loaded successfully, but that function can accept `Floating` typeclass value, and I just wanted it to accept `Integer`s. So I added a type annotation on top of it.

```hs
f :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> [b]
f x = map sqrt [1..x]
```

Out of my expectation, it was failed to load. An error was thrown at the GHCi's REPL:

```
1.hs:48:7: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          f :: forall a b. (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> [b]
        at 1.hs:47:1-41
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          f :: forall a b. (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> [b]
        at 1.hs:47:1-41
      Expected type: [b]
        Actual type: [a]
    • In the expression: map sqrt [1 .. x]
      In an equation for ‘f’: f x = map sqrt [1 .. x]
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at 1.hs:48:3)
        f :: a -> [b] (bound at 1.hs:48:1)
   |
48 | f x = map sqrt [1..x]
   |       ^^
```

I completely lost my mind, and had no idea what the error was talking about. It seems to complain that the result type should be `[a]` instead of `[b]`. But that was absurd, since `a` was a member of type class `Integral`, and the function definitely would return a list of `Floating` number. It just didn't make any sense.

Can anyone explains why the error happened, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that [**`sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) will always map numbers to numbers of the *same* type, notice the `a -> a` in the type signature. It also requires the numbers to be an instance of `Floating`, and although technically speaking you can make a type that is an instance of both `Integral` and `Floating`, this does not make much sense.

If you write `[ 1 .. x ]` you generate a list of items with the same type as `x`. So if `x` is `Integral a => a`, then `[ 1 .. x ]` has type `Integral a => [a]` (and it is the same `a`). Your type signature however says that for every `Integral` type `a`, you can produce any list of elements of a `Floating` type `b`.

You can make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert integral numbers to another type of numbers, so you can write this as:

```
f :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> [b]
f x = map (sqrt . fromIntegral) [1..x]
```

Comment: It was kind of odd that GHCi assume `sqrt` could accept `Integral` value and kept deducing 
. Why? I mean, if it could prompt something like **sqrt requires a `Floating` value, but got `Integral`**, I would be easier to figure out the mistake.

Comment: @Stephen.W: it didn't. If you write `map sqrt [1 .. x]` it will assume `x` has type `Floating a => a`. You can query for the type with `:t \x -> map sqrt [ 1 .. x ]` in ghci, and it will specify `Floating a => a -> [a]`. Note that if you write `5` it is just `Num` type, so it can be deduced to both an `Integral` or `Floating` type.